# Fuzzy Images on Android Buttons

Tags: android, image, button, image-processing

I got beautiful .png images in `32x32px` and when I set them in my android app as buttons like this :

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graph));
```

they're all ugly and fuzzy

but, idk why I added them in all drawable folders but it wont change anything !

Any ideas ?

Here is the screen shot (eventhough it doesnt look as fuzzy as it really is..) : 
[image]

Comment: how is the size of Your button? Could You post a screenshot?

Comment: I dont set a size .. I think the size depends on the size of the image, I create it like that : 

button = new Button(getBaseContext());
  button.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graph));

Comment: If it is possible, define Your views (eg Your button) inside a xml layout. Anyway, for setting images to a button, an ImageButton is the better solution...

Comment: Please see screen shot edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to dynamically set your buttons to Wrap_Content :

```
Button pf = new Button(context);
pf.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Otherwise, it's better to declare this params in Xml file :

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageReco"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
```

Enjoy

Comment: I already had that but it doesnt change the quality .. Thank you tho

Comment: What type of layout do you use ? Print your xml ;)

Comment: I dont use any xml files .. I create tabs dynamically so I had to create its layout dynamically too !